# HTML 5 Canvas Game Regularly Stuttering

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

a game I have been making recently seems to stutter at regular intervals. I have looked into it and the FPS stays consistent and I can't see something in the code that would cause stuttering like it (I know setInterval isn't great though). The weird thing is that the game runs fine in Internet Explorer but not in any other browser. Have also tried on several different PCs / laptops to make sure it wasn't a computer performance issue. Any help is greatly appreciated, here is a small section of the code I cut out to show off the issue. I can provide the full thing if needed but it is pretty long.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="625"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var imageDuckUp = new Image();
imageDuckUp.src = "images/duckUp.png";

var imageDuckDown = new Image();
imageDuckDown.src = "images/duckDown.png";

var duckVelocity = 3;
var duckAcceleration = 1.03;
var duckMaxVelocity = 20;
var currentImage = imageDuckUp;

var duckXPos = 300;
var duckYPos = 50;

function moveDrawDuck() 
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (duckVelocity > 0 && duckVelocity < duckMaxVelocity)
    {
        duckVelocity = duckAcceleration * duckVelocity;
    }
    duckYPos += duckVelocity;
    ctx.drawImage(currentImage, duckXPos, duckYPos, currentImage.width, currentImage.height);
}
function update()
{
    moveDrawDuck();
}

var timer = setInterval(update, 1000 / 60);

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseClickDown, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseClickUp, false);

function mouseClickDown(e)
{
    currentImage = imageDuckDown;
    duckVelocity = -3;
}

function mouseClickUp()
{
    currentImage = imageDuckUp;
    duckVelocity = 3;
}
```

>

Comment: What do you mean by **stutter at regular intervals** ?

Comment: The game when ran in Chrome appears to be laggy - every half a second or so the bird will appear to 'jump' as if the Y position was increased by 6 instead of 3 (whilst holding the left mouse key down)